# Who has done gitops with aws ssm and secrets parameters in codepipeline?

Tags: github, aws-codepipeline, aws-secrets-manager, aws-ssm

Just wondering who has implemented the use of github and updating ssm parameters and secrets within a codepipeline and what's the best practices around that.

I was thinking of putting some cli commands in a shell script in github and use codepipeline to migrate it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a command or API execution is required in CodePipeline, think about these 3 options (i.e. Actions):

1. CodeBuild (best to execute a command)
2. Lambda (More suited for API execution)
3. Custom Action (for advanced usage, you control the action completely)

So based on this, I would say CodeBuild will be the easiest option for your use case to run the command. Use a "latest" "[curated image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html)" so the execution is fastest for your CodeBuild job.

Comment: So, are you saying, put an SSM script in github along with the regular deployments? What happens if there are errors or you need rollback because one of the 20 ssm cli commands fail?